# Microsoft Graph API : mass / bulk data exports for a tenant?

Tags: export, office365, microsoft-graph-api, yammer

Would it be possible to massively export data from a Microsoft tenant (tenant.onmicrosoft.com), such as all users calendar events, OneDrive documents list, etc., between two given dates, using Microsoft Graph API (or any other API) ?

Like mass exports of messages, users and groups with **[Yammer Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api)** for those who know.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [Microsoft Graph Data Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/data-connect-concept-overview) as it allows you to do bulk exports of graph data for all or a subset of your users.  Depending on the data set you want there is some date filtering as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally such APIs are snapshots.  I'm not sure what data you would expect to vary by date range in that scenario other than the calendar?  There is no bulk API on the Graph or to my knowledge in older APIs for those underlying services, but you could use the Graph to do the walk manually using app-only tokens and flows.  There would be no guarantees of a coherent snapshot in such an approach though, and you would have to engineer to watch for throttling, back off and retry appropriately.